# How to monitor alarms from MySQL with openNMS

Tags: mysql, opennms

Is it possible to monitor alarms from MySQL (or at least MySQL service availability) with openNMS?

If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

There are couple ways listed here 
http://opennms.530661.n2.nabble.com/MYSQL-MONITORING-WITH-OPENNMS-td5865036.html 
and another one is here 
http://www.masterzen.fr/software-contributions/mysql-snmp-monitor-mysql-with-snmp/

Comment: I don't need any statistics, just the availability of the database